# How to add a custom table with data from the database to the application in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to add to an application in **Oracle APEX** a small module similar to **static HTML** but which **retrieves data from a database**.

That is, a customized table with data from the database.

Is it possible to do something like this in Oracle APEX?

Comment: There are a number of different page items that will do this for you in APEX. Depending on how you want the data to be used, an Interactive Report or a Classic Report might be what you're after. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/htmdb/developing-reports.html#GUID-A63ECD33-D759-4725-9666-A02719FB35B8 could be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I used PL/SQL Dynamic content:

```
declare
begin
for rec in (select CATEGORY_TITLE from TBL_CATEGORY)
loop
htp.p('<table style="border: 2px solid #eee;">');
htp.p('<tr>');
htp.p('<td>'||'Category: '||'</td>'||'<td>'||rec.CATEGORY_TITLE||'</td>'||'<td>'||'</td>'||'<td>'||'</td>');
htp.p('</tr>');
htp.p('</table>');
htp.p('<br>');
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: You answered your own question - great :) Pls close the question (since it no longer requires input from anyone else)